# multidimensional array bufferedreader

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, bufferedreader

How can I make `num1` and `num2` combine in one `readLine`? I mean, for example, if I type number 11 on question `num1`, it will automatically be Mike. Is it possible? Here's the code.

```
import java.io.*;
class array {

    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String [][] names = {
              {"Mike", "Mateo"}, {"Darcy", "Yalong"}, {"Karlo", "Pilapil"},
              {"Naomi", "Balmaceda"}
        };

        int num1, num2;
        System.out.print("Enter a number from 1 to 4: ");
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter another number, 1 or 2: ");
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        System.out.print(names[num1-1][num2-1]);

    }
}
```

Comment: You mean if you type `1`, not `11`, right?

Comment: Oh, I got it, you want both first indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You can take input in string form and convert it into char arrays:-

```
char s[]=br.readLine().toCharArray();
int num1=Integer.parseInt(""+s[0]);
int num2=Integer.parseInt(""+s[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Integer.parseInt() and converting characters to strings you can use one of the java.lang.Character.digit() methods:

```
String line = ...;
int num1 = Character.digit( line.charAt(0), 10 ); 
int num2 = Character.digit( line.charAt(1), 10 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user types 11, then this will get the data `num1 = 1` and `num2 = 1` in one `readLine`:

```
String line = br.readLine();
num1 = Integer.parseInt(""+line.charAt(0));
num2 = Integer.parseInt(""+line.charAt(1));
```

If you have lists where the selectors are numbers with more than one digit, you might want to use a separator like a space, comma, semicolon, and then split the string.

Comment: parseInt cannot parse char to int but its right syntax is parseInt(String str).

Comment: Yes. I overlooked that. I edited the code converting it to String. It should work now.